# Forward slash "/" concatenation for STATIC_ROOT and MEDIA_ROOT (Django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, concatenation

I found sometimes **forward slash "/"** is used to concatenate **"BASE_DIR"** and **"static"** or **"media"** for **"STATIC_ROOT"** and **"MEDIA_ROOT"** in **"settings.py"** as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"
                     # Here
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'
                    # Here
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

So, it's possible to concatenate **BASE_DIR** which is **'PosixPath' type** and **'static'** which is **'str' type** with **forward slash "/"**.

But when I tried to concatenate **'str' type** and **'str' type** with **"/"**:

```py
# "settings.py"

STATIC_ROOT = 'abc' / 'static'
```

I got this error below:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

And for **'int' type** and **'str' type** with **"/"**:

```py
STATIC_ROOT = 123 / 'static'
```

I got this error below:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'

Then for **'MyClass' type** and **'str' type** with **"/"**:

```py
# "settings.py"

class MyClass:
    pass

STATIC_ROOT = MyClass() / 'static'
```

I got this error below:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'MyClass' and 'str'

So, can we only concatenate **'PosixPath' type** and **'str' type** with **forward slash "/"**? Aren't there any other types to concatenate with **forward slash "/"**?

Comment: Since Django-3.0, it uses `Path` objects for paths...

Comment: In Python, the slash means floating-point divide. It is always possible when you write your own class to define an operator to work differently. So, it makes sense to subtract one date from another (yields difference in days) but it makes no sense to take the modulo of a date. But you might write your own subclass of `datetime.date` that treats `mydate % 7` as valid, and returns, say, the previous Sunday. The authors of `pathlib` chose to redefine `/` as a path concatenation operator.  It works with `Path` and subclasses and does the right thing on all platforms. Do not overgeneralize.

Answer (score 1):

`Django==3.x` use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), which allow you to use / to concatenate paths.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve the same behaviour in one of your classes you will have to implement the method [`__truediv__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__truediv__).

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return Thing(self.name + other)


thing = Thing('Monty')
other_thing = thing / 'Python'
print(other_thing.name)
```

This will give you the output `MontyPython`.

If you want to be able to concatenate not only a `Thing` instance and a string but two `Thing` instances you have to check the type of `other`.

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Thing):
            return Thing(self.name + other.name)
        return Thing(self.name + other)


thing = Thing('Monty')
thing2 = Thing('Python')
other_thing = thing / thing2
print(other_thing.name)
```